Wazuh dashboard HTML file
I have a chatbot and I want to integrate this chatbot into Wazuh Dashboard. For this, I need to add the script code of my chatbot to the Wazuh HTML file, but I cannot find the folder containing the HTML codes of the Wazuh dashboard. Can you help?
I copied an element of the HTML code on the Wazuh Dashboard page that did not contain the id attribute and searched for this HTML code on the server where the wazuh manager is located, but I did not get any results.
